# min cut for multiple partitions

Tags: algorithms, graphs, randomized-algorithms, partitions

So I am familiar with the standard minimum cut problem in which the goal is to find the smallest possible set of edges in a graph such that, upon their removal, we have two nonempty, disjoint partitions of vertices with no connecting edges between partitions. There exist randomized edge-contraction algorithms to solve this problem.

What if we want to solve the min-cut problem for more than two partitions? What would be the nature of the algorithms used to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Your Google search term is "multiway cut".